# Can if-the-else in one object reference to another object in JSOPN schema

Tags: if-statement, jsonschema

Is something like this possible in JSON schema?

```
{
    "properties": {
        "obj1": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "prop1": {"type": "integer"}
            }
        },
        "obj2": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "prop2": {"type": "integer"}
            },
            "if": {
                "properties": {"obj1/prop1": { "const": 1}}
            }, 
            "then": {
                "required": ["prop2"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Meaning that if obj1.prop1 has value 1 then obj2.prop2 is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and your approach is almost there. You can't reference other properties "up-the-tree". Instead, you have to layer the schemas from the point where they diverge. For your situation, this looks like this:

```json
{
   "properties":{
      "obj1":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "prop1":{
               "type":"integer"
            }
         }
      },
      "obj2":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "prop2":{
               "type":"integer"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "if":{
      "properties":{
         "obj1":{
            "properties":{
               "prop1":{
                  "const":1
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "then":{
      "properties":{
         "obj2":{
            "required":[
               "prop2"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You first define the common schema bits in `properties`. Then, you use `if/then` to layer situational schema constraints on top.